# Select first and second half of list items

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to change the color of list items based on a gradient with a defined starting color and ending color. I'm trying to use two different color stops for the 1st and 2nd half of my list items. The problem is that only the first half is working and I get a JS error

https://jsfiddle.net/qrzms3s9/1/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  if($('.test')[0]){

    var circles = $('.testcircle').length,
            halfcircles = circles / 2;  

    function colorStrToIntArray(color) {
        if (color.length == 4 || color.length == 7) {
                color = color.substr(1);
        }
        if (color.length == 3) {
            var r = parseInt(color.substr(0, 1) + color.substr(0, 1), 16),
                    g = parseInt(color.substr(1, 1) + color.substr(1, 1), 16),
                    b = parseInt(color.substr(2, 1) + color.substr(2, 1), 16);

            return [r, g, b];
        } 
        else if (color.length == 6) {
            return [
                parseInt(color.substr(0, 2), 16), 
                parseInt(color.substr(2, 2), 16), 
                parseInt(color.substr(4, 2), 16)
            ];
        }
        return false;
    }

    function calculateSteps(color1, color2, steps) {
        var output = [],
                start = colorStrToIntArray(color1),
                end = colorStrToIntArray(color2);
        var calculate = function(start, end, step) {
            return start + Math.round((end - start) * (step / (steps / 2)));
        };
        for ( var i = 0; i < steps; i++ ) {
            var color = [0, 0, 0];
            color[0] = calculate(start[0], end[0], i);
            color[1] = calculate(start[1], end[1], i);
            color[2] = calculate(start[2], end[2], i);
            output.push(color);
        }
        return output;
    }

    var colors = calculateSteps("#f29111", "#e60000", halfcircles),
            colors2 = calculateSteps("#d20911", "#22637e", halfcircles),
            cars = $('.testcircle');
            index = 0;

    $('.testcircle').each(function() {
        var $carrot = $("<div>", {"class": "testw6"});
        $(this).closest('li').find('.testw5').prepend($carrot);
        if (index < halfcircles) { 
            $(this).css('background-color', 'rgb(' + colors[index][0] + ', ' + colors[index][1] + ', ' + colors[index][2] + ')');
            $(this).closest('li').find('.testw5').css('background-color', 'rgb(' + colors[index][0] + ', ' + colors[index][1] + ', ' + colors[index][2] + ')');
            $(this).closest('li').find('.testw6').css('background-color', 'rgb(' + colors[index][0] + ', ' + colors[index][1] + ', ' + colors[index][2] + ')');
            index++;
        }
        else {
            $(this).css('background-color', 'rgb(' + colors2[index][0] + ', ' + colors2[index][1] + ', ' + colors2[index][2] + ')');
            $(this).closest('li').find('.testw5').css('background-color', 'rgb(' + colors2[index][0] + ', ' + colors2[index][1] + ', ' + colors2[index][2] + ')');
            $(this).closest('li').find('.testw6').css('background-color', 'rgb(' + colors2[index][0] + ', ' + colors2[index][1] + ', ' + colors2[index][2] + ')');
            index++;
        }
    });

  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is with your `index` count. For the second half of iteration you need to reset the `index`. I have a better approach for the code - instead of resetting the index, we can have a single array of `colors` and point the element index from `each`.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  var circles = $('.testcircle').length,
    halfcircles = circles / 2;

  function colorStrToIntArray(color) {
    if (color.length == 4 || color.length == 7) {
      color = color.substr(1);
    }
    if (color.length == 3) {
      var r = parseInt(color.substr(0, 1) + color.substr(0, 1), 16),
        g = parseInt(color.substr(1, 1) + color.substr(1, 1), 16),
        b = parseInt(color.substr(2, 1) + color.substr(2, 1), 16);

      return [r, g, b];
    } else if (color.length == 6) {
      return [
        parseInt(color.substr(0, 2), 16),
        parseInt(color.substr(2, 2), 16),
        parseInt(color.substr(4, 2), 16)
      ];
    }
    return false;
  }

  function calculateSteps(color1, color2, steps) {
    var output = [],
      start = colorStrToIntArray(color1),
      end = colorStrToIntArray(color2);
    var calculate = function(start, end, step) {
      return start + Math.round((end - start) * (step / (steps / 2)));
    };
    for (var i = 0; i < steps; i++) {
      var color = [0, 0, 0];
      color[0] = calculate(start[0], end[0], i);
      color[1] = calculate(start[1], end[1], i);
      color[2] = calculate(start[2], end[2], i);
      output.push(color);
    }
    return output;
  }

  var colors = calculateSteps("#f29111", "#e60000", halfcircles),
    cars = $('.testcircle');
  colors = colors.concat(calculateSteps("#d20911", "#22637e", halfcircles));

  $('.testcircle').each(function(i) {
    var $carrot = $("<div>", {
      "class": "testw6"
    });
    var rgb = 'rgb(' + colors[i][0] + ', ' + colors[i][1] + ', ' + colors[i][2] + ')';
    $(this).closest('li').find('.testw5').prepend($carrot);
    $(this).css('background-color', rgb);
    $(this).closest('li').find('.testw5').css('background-color', rgb);
    $(this).closest('li').find('.testw6').css('background-color', rgb);
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="testw3">
  <ul class="testw4">
    <li>
      <a href="placeholder.html">
        <span class="testcircle"><span class="testnumber">10</span></span>
        <div class="testtext">Title</div>
        <div class="testw5">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
          <a href="placeholder.html">Lorem Ipsum Link</a>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="placeholder.html">
        <span class="testcircle"><span class="testnumber">10</span></span>
        <div class="testtext">Title</div>
        <div class="testw5">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
          <a href="placeholder.html">Lorem Ipsum Link</a>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="placeholder.html">
        <span class="testcircle"><span class="testnumber">10</span></span>
        <div class="testtext">Title</div>
        <div class="testw5">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
          <a href="placeholder.html">Lorem Ipsum Link</a>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="placeholder.html">
        <span class="testcircle"><span class="testnumber">10</span></span>
        <div class="testtext">Title</div>
        <div class="testw5">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
          <a href="placeholder.html">Lorem Ipsum Link</a>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="placeholder.html">
        <span class="testcircle"><span class="testnumber">10</span></span>
        <div class="testtext">Title</div>
        <div class="testw5">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
          <a href="placeholder.html">Lorem Ipsum Link</a>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="placeholder.html">
        <span class="testcircle"><span class="testnumber">10</span></span>
        <div class="testtext">Title</div>
        <div class="testw5">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
          <a href="placeholder.html">Lorem Ipsum Link</a>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="placeholder.html">
        <span class="testcircle"><span class="testnumber">10</span></span>
        <div class="testtext">Title</div>
        <div class="testw5">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
          <a href="placeholder.html">Lorem Ipsum Link</a>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="placeholder.html">
        <span class="testcircle"><span class="testnumber">10</span></span>
        <div class="testtext">Title</div>
        <div class="testw5">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
          <a href="placeholder.html">Lorem Ipsum Link</a>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="placeholder.html">
        <span class="testcircle"><span class="testnumber">10</span></span>
        <div class="testtext">Title</div>
        <div class="testw5">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
          <a href="placeholder.html">Lorem Ipsum Link</a>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="placeholder.html">
        <span class="testcircle"><span class="testnumber">10</span></span>
        <div class="testtext">Title</div>
        <div class="testw5">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
          <a href="placeholder.html">Lorem Ipsum Link</a>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: can u mark as resolve, if this solves your problem :)